# Cannot access number key in Racket hash table?

Tags: hash, racket

So I'm trying to access a hash table in Racket, but I can not figure out why it's not working.

When I call `hash->list` on this hash:

```
{"26220765": [
{
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "name": "Viktor's Marauders",
  "participantId": "26220765",
  "entries": [
     {
        "leaguePoints": 0,
        "isFreshBlood": false,
        "isHotStreak": false,
        "division": "IV",
        "isInactive": false,
        "isVeteran": true,
        "losses": 168,
        "playerOrTeamName": "iGT500",
        "playerOrTeamId": "32156611",
        "wins": 173
     },
     {
        "leaguePoints": 0,
        "isFreshBlood": true,
        "isHotStreak": false,
        "division": "V",
        "isInactive": false,
        "isVeteran": false,
        "losses": 255,
        "playerOrTeamName": "dragdan",
        "playerOrTeamId": "20430418",
        "wins": 265
     },
```

It returns

```
((|26220765| #hasheq((name . "Viktor's Marauders") (queue . "RANKED_SOLO_5x5") (tier . "PLATINUM") (entries . (#hasheq((playerOrTeamId . "32156611") (division . "IV") (playerOrTeamName . "iGT500") (leaguePoints . 0) (wins . 173) (losses . 168) (isHotStreak . #f) (isVeteran . #t) (isFreshBlood . #f) (isInactive . #f)) #hasheq((playerOrTeamId . "20430418") (division . "V") (playerOrTeamName . "dragdan") (leaguePoints . 0) (wins . 265) (losses . 255) (isHotStreak . #f) (isVeteran . #f)
```

I can not access the hash by using the key 26220765.  I've tried defining it as `summoner-id` and passing it, i've tried using `'26220765`, it doesn't work.  I don't understand why it's being displayed with vertical bars, and if I try `'|26220765|` or `|26220765|` it doesn't work either.

I had another hash table where I needed to access the hash `"champions"`, and using `'champions` worked, so why isn't this working?

Comment: Using `'|26220765|` should work. It's being displayed with vertical bars because it's a symbol, but it's only composed of numeric characters, so it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @AlexisKing '|26220765 works, I don't know what I was doing before.  But what if I have the number 26220765 defined as `summoner-id`?  basically I need `'|summoner-id|`, but I think I need to escape `summoner-id` so what's between the '| | is a number, but that number changes depending on who I look up with the API.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `summoner-id` a string or a number?

Comment: @AlexisKing It's a number; I ended up doing this: `(define summ-key 
      (if (not (hash? league-hash-json))
          (printf "No ranked data to judge.\n")
          (hash-keys league-hash-json)))`

because at this particular point, it's always returning a hash with the id as the key, and another hash as teh value, and i found that hash-keys lists all the keys in a hash, but only the outtermost layer, if you get what I mean? so this will always be a list with the correct id, so I just take the car of the list and I know it will always match(if they exist).  thanks for your help though!

Comment: You probably want to use `(string->symbol (number->string summoner-id))`.

Comment: @AlexisKing -.- I swear i'm confusing myself.  I'm doing multiple calls to different parts of the API, and I had that exact code working for one, but for some reason wasn't working for another, i rewrote my code and changed random things, and finally ended up with the `summ-key` method, which works, and now when I put back in the `string->symbol` code, that works too.  This project is driving me crazy, racket just makes no sense to me, coming from working exclusively with c++

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#lang racket/base
(require json)
(define js (string->jsexpr "{\"123\": \"val\"}"))
js ;=> '#hasheq((|123| . "val"))
(hash-ref js '|123|) ;=> "val"
```

Do you have a similarly short example of what *doesn't* work for you?

p.s. You may find people more motivated to answer, if you take a moment to accept and/or upvote answers. Like [Racket string to literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360497/racket-string-to-literal) and [Getting a specific hash-table from a list in racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597300/getting-a-specific-hash-table-from-a-list-in-racket).

Comment: It says I need to have 15 reputation to update something,  which is why I haven't been doing that,  and maybe a it's because I'm on mobile but I do not see a way to pick answer and Mark my question as solved

Answer (score 0):

In Racket there are different constructors for hash tables. The difference between them is that the hash table uses different comparators (eq? , equal? , eqv?, ...).

That's probably the reason why it doesn't work always like you would want it to.
[The different hash tables in racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html)

In fact when making a hash table it has to know which comparator to use to check for equality. You could for example imagine a generic implementation where you have to pass your own lambda to be used as comparator.